# Помогите исправить код к задаче на ПИТОН

Tags: python

1. Дан текст на русском языке, за которым следует точка. В алфавитном порядке напечатать по одному разу все строчные согласные буквы, входящие в этот текст.

```
s = input()
print(s)
a = ['а','е','ё','и','о','у','ы','э','ю','я']
for sym in a:
    if sym in s:
        print(sym, end='')
        a.remove(sym)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: 1 - Этот вопрос в данный момент включает несколько вопросов. Его следует переформулировать, чтобы он был сфокусирован только на одной проблеме. 2 - Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Вы можете просто решить задачу? в прошлом году была учительница с Украины, уехала, в материале дырка. Новый преподаватель эту дырку в учет не берет.

Comment: @Львенок, нет, не можем, это не сервис для решения учебных задач. Можем помочь, если что-то не получается, но вам нужно описать, что не так с вашим кодом - конкретные ошибки или проблемы.

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («**почему этот код не работает?**») должны включать желаемое поведение, *конкретную проблему или ошибку* и *минимальный код* для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы без **явного описания проблемы** бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

```
s = input()
print(s)
a = ['б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'ж', 'з', 'й', 'к', 'л', 'м', 'н', 'п', 'р', 'с', 
'т', 'ф', 'х', 'ц', 'ч', 'ш', 'щ']
for i in a:
    if i in s:
        print(i)
```

Если я правильно понял, то вот что ты хотел получить.